# why is message.channel.awaitMessages() not working? | Discord.js V13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to collect a message after a certain message a user has sent in a specific channel. So the user would send say `hello world` then await messages would wait for a response from a specific user and grab that message's ID. However, it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
let filter = message => {
    return message.author.id == 'ID OF USER';
}

if(message.channel.id == 'channel id of sent message') {
            console.log('here');
            if(message.content.valueOf("hello world")) {
                console.log('here');
                message.channel.awaitMessages(bumpFilter, { max: 1, time: 5000, errors: ['time']})
                .then(c => {
                    console.log('here');
                    console.log(c);
                });
            }
        }
```

In the console, `here` is logged 2 times. However, the 3rd time is not logged, even after the 5 seconds has passed from this message. The console logs nothing, not even an error, which got me to speculate that maybe it's an discord intents issue, but i don't think that was it either. So i don't understand what's the issue and why I won't get any results. Also, if i assigned `message.channel.awaitMessages(...)` to a `var` then logged the `var` it would output `Promise { <pending> }` and I read that a `.then` statement has to be added to avoid that. And now that it is added, it still does not output anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `if (message.content.valueOf("hello world"))` will always return true as the [`valueOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) returns the primitive value of the specified object. Even if `message.content` is not `"hello world"`, it's still truthy. You should check if the value of `message.content` itself is equal to `"hello world"`.

Second, you declare a `filter` variable but you use `bumpFilter` in your `awaitMessages`

And third, in discord.js v13, [`awaitMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) accepts a single parameter, an [options object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AwaitMessagesOptions). (In v12 the first parameter was a filter and the second one is the options).

```js
let filter = (message) => {
  return message.author.id === 'ID OF USER';
};

if (message.channel.id === 'channel id of sent message') {
  console.log('channel matches');

  if (message.content === 'hello world') {
    console.log('message is hello world');

    message.channel
      .awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 5000, errors: ['time'] })
      .then((c) => {
        console.log('New message collected');
        console.log(c);
      })
      .catch((c) =>
        console.log(`After five seconds, ${c.size} messages are collected.`),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great it works :) However, is there a way to get the message ID through c? `c.id` doesn't seem to work just returns `undefined`, What would be the best way to get the ID?

Comment: That's great to hear. `c` is a [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection), not a single message. If you only collect one message, you can use `c.first().id` to grab the message ID.

Comment: Thank you very much :D

Comment: You're welcome :)