# Collector doesn't end with reason time

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I got this jumbled words code where it ends if nobody got the right answer after the time has ran out. But the collector doesn't end somehow. The code works just fine but I wanted the collector to end in a given limited time.

This was the code:

```js
const listword = ['array', 'of', 'words'];

var word = listword[Math.floor(Math.random() * listword.length)].toLowerCase();
var jumbled = word
  .split('')
  .sort(function () {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
  })
  .join('');

interaction.followUp({ content: `The word is ${word}`, ephemeral: true });
await interaction.channel.send(`Guess the word \`${jumbled}\`!`);
const filter = (response) => listword.includes(response.content.trim());

const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
  time: 15000, //this doesn't work somehow
});
collector.on('collect', (response) => {
  if (response.author.bot) return;
  var guessword = response.content.trim();
  if (guessword.toLowerCase() === word) {
    response.react('✅');
    response.reply({
      content: `${response.author} guessed it right! The word was \`${word}\`.`,
      allowedMentions: { users: [], roles: [], repliedUser: false },
    });
    collector.stop();
  } else {
    if (response.author.bot) return;
    response.react('❌');
  }
});

collector.on('end', (collected) => {
  if (!collected.size) {
    interaction.channel.send(
      'Time is up! Nobody was able to guess the word' + `\`${word}\`.`
    );
  }
});
```

I don't know why the collector doesn't end unless the word is guessed correctly. What do I need do to fix it?

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: I'm using version 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discord.js v13, all Collector related classes and methods (both `.create*()` and `.await*()`) takes a single object parameter. That means,  [`createMessageCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageCollector) accepts a single parameter, an [`options`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorOptions) object. (previously, the first parameter was a `filter` and the second one is the `options`).

As you provide the `filter` as the first argument, the object with the `time` key is simply ignored. Just pass a single object with the `filter` and the `time` and it will work fine:

```js
const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({
  filter,
  time: 15000,
});
```

Similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70455975/6126373

Comment: Wait, I tried and followed your correction (I put the `filter` together with the `time` in the object) but then I got a problem (no errors). The collector ended with the time limit however, it stopped collecting messages nor did it react ✅/❌. I tried putting the `filter` outside the object and it collected messages again but there's the problem with the `time` again. Sorry I can't really figure how to make it work. I wanted it to collect messages (word guesses although wrong) and also ends the collector with the limited time even if the collected messages are wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see, your `filter` allows you to collect messages if it's one of the words. It means the `collect` event won't trigger if the `response.content` is not in the `listword` array. So, e.g. if the value of `word` is `"array"`, and the user send a message `"rayar"`, the collector will not do anything as it's not the correct word. If you want to react in either way, just remove the `filter` altogether.

Comment: I never thought of that at all. Now it works as I wanted it to be! Thank you again!