# The bot does not reply to my DM || Discord.js V.14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is my code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ChannelType } = require('discord.js');
const { generateCaptcha } = require('../../Models/Captcha')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('setup-verification')
        .setDescription('Sets up a verification system in your server'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        // Check if user is an Administrator
        if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator)) {
            return interaction.reply({ content: 'You do not have permission to use this command.', ephemeral: true });
        }

        // Check if server already has Verified and Unverified roles
        const verifiedRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Verified');
        const unverifiedRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Unverified');
        if (verifiedRole || unverifiedRole) {
            return interaction.reply({ content: 'Your server already has a verification system set up.', ephemeral: true });
        }

        // Create Verified and Unverified roles
        const newVerifiedRole = await interaction.guild.roles.create({
            name: 'Verified',
            color: '0xff0000',
            reason: 'Verified role for verification system',
        });
        const newUnverifiedRole = await interaction.guild.roles.create({
            name: 'Unverified',
            color: '0x00ff0c',
            reason: 'Unverified role for verification system',
        });

        // Create verification channel
        const verificationChannel = await interaction.guild.channels.create({
            name: 'verification',
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone.id,
                    deny: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel],
                },
                {
                    id: newUnverifiedRole.id,
                    allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel],
                    deny: [PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages],
                },
            ],
            reason: 'Verification channel for verification system',
        });

        // Create verification message with button
        const captcha = generateCaptcha();
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Verification System')
            .setDescription('Click the button below to start the verification process.');
        const button = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('verification:start')
            .setLabel('Verify')
            .setStyle('Primary');
        const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(button);
        const message = await verificationChannel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] });

        // Listen for button click
        const filter = i => i.customId === 'verification:start' && i.user.id === interaction.user.id;
        const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 30000 });

        collector.on('collect', async i => {
            try {
                // Send captcha to user's DMs
                const dmChannel = await i.user.createDM();
                const dmMessage = await dmChannel.send(`Please enter the following captcha within 30 seconds: **${captcha}**`);
                const dmFilter = m => m.author.id === i.user.id;
                const dmCollector = dmChannel.createMessageCollector(dmFilter, { time: 30000 });

                // Check captcha response
                dmCollector.on('collect', async m => {
                console.log('Message collected:', m.content);
                console.log('Expected captcha:', captcha);
                if (m.content === captcha) {
                    console.log('Verification successful');
                    dmChannel.send('You have been verified!');
                    await i.member.roles.add(newVerifiedRole);
                    await i.member.roles.remove(newUnverifiedRole);
                    await i.update({ components: [row] });
                } else {
                    console.log('Incorrect captcha');
                    dmChannel.send('Incorrect captcha. Please try again.');
                }
                dmCollector.stop();
                });

                // Handle timeout
                dmCollector.on('end', async collected => {
                if (!dmMessage.deleted) {
                    dmMessage.delete();
                }
                if (collected.size === 0) {
                    dmChannel.send('Time is up. Please try again.');
                }
                try {
                    await i.update({ components: [row] });
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(`Error updating message: ${err}`);
                }
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    
        // Generate random captcha
        function generateCaptcha() {
            const length = 6;
            const charset = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&()_+{}|:?><,./;';
            let captcha = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                captcha += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));
            }
            return captcha;
        }

        const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Create Verification Process - Success')
        .setDescription(`Successfully setup the Verification!`)
        .setColor(0x5fb041)
        .setTimestamp()

        await interaction.reply({
            embeds: [embed2],
    })
    },
}
```

When I click the button on the Verification Channel the bot sends me a message with the ${captcha} code and then I must reply with the ${captcha} code. If I reply correctly I get the verified role in the Server with a success message (in the DM), if I reply with the wrong ${captcha} it will just send a failure message (in the DM). The problem is here: "// Check captcha response..." after sending me the message with the ${captcha} and repling with the verification ${captcha} code it simply does not reply back, when the time is out (30 seconds) it sends 'Time is up. Please try again.' and the bot crashes! Any answer is accepted, thanks!

Comment: What intents have you enabled?

Comment: Intents: [Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages, MessageContent],

Comment: Shouldn't you add the `dmFilter` inside the options object? Like `dmChannel.createMessageCollector({ filter: dmFilter, time: 30000, })`. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75265765/collector-doesnt-end-with-reason-time/75266594#75266594

Comment: Didn't work: "Error updating message: DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out! I just forgot to add the `DirectMessages` intent on my `index.js` file.

The correct code is:

```
const { Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages, MessageContent, DirectMessages } = GatewayIntentBits;

const client = new Client({
    intents: [Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages, MessageContent, DirectMessages],
    partials: [User, Message, GuildMember, ThreadMember],
});
```