# message.channel.awaitMessages() not working? | Discord.js V14

Tags: discord.js

I resurrected a bot I had from a while ago but can get it to read Dm responses in Discordjs V14.

I have DirectMessages intents specified, It will send the Question via DM but not react to a response.

```
await appChannel.send('Name?');
      let answer1 = await appChannel.awaitMessages(answer1 => answer1.author.id != client.user.id, { max: 1 });
      const name = (answer1.map(answers => answers.content).join());
```

I Have a series of questions that then get posted to a discord channel using MessageEmbed()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is message.channel.awaitMessages() not working? | Discord.js V13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70455704/why-is-message-channel-awaitmessages-not-working-discord-js-v13)

Comment: Also, if moving the filter doesn't work, can you add the intents array you use when you initialise your client?

Comment: This may have fixed it, Im working though some other issues currently.